# Restart and resume applications like in OSX

Tags: backup, reboot, restore

In OSX there is this restart and resume feature, that makes every window of every application (that supports this feature) resume after a system reboot, even unsaved new documents, mails, images etc.

I wonder, if and how it is possible to imitate this feature on an Ubuntu system. There is [tuxonice](http://tuxonice.nigelcunningham.com.au/) but I am not quite sure if that actually does what I want.

To clarify, I am not talking about hibernating or suspend to disk. After a true reboot and even after hard resetting the machine everything is back as before. I use it with [TextEdit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextEdit) to hold notes a lot, but also with unfinished emails in [Mail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_%28application%29). It would be really cool to have this on Ubuntu as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd love this for *Ubuntu Mate* also. It's essentially like "suspend" where you can turn on the computer and it remembers everything that was open.. well why not the same but remember after reboot.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/15528-ubuntu-automatically-restore-last-opened-programs-at-next-sessi) worked for me when connecting remotely to a machine and logging in/out. Will test in a few hours at home with a full reboot, will edit with my findings

I also found [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/203952/how-to-automatically-remember-running-applications-from-your-last-session-in-ubuntu-14.04/) which seems to do exactly the same.

I have never thought about this feature before and glad you brought it up!

**EDIT**
I run Gnome 3 and wasn't able to find the setting as mentioned in the first article
The second article also didn't work for me

**EDIT 2**
Neither article worked for me in Ubuntu 14.04 using Unity or Gnome 3

Comment: This restores the running applications but it certainly does not restore any unsaved files. Instead, when shutting down, pluma for example prevented the shutdown with a "save me first" dialog. Thats more like the opposite of what I want. Upvote for at least restoring apps, though.

Comment: I don't think that is possible unless the app supports it directly. Glad it helped somewhat